# Bringing values ​according to the selected title in the imported excel sheet

Tags: c#, loops

In the application, I select the titles of the Excel file I imported from the checkboxes I created dynamically and keep these selections in the listSecili List. Then, I add the row values ​​in Excel to the bolunmusDeger List. What I want to do is to bring the values ​​under the headings in Excel according to the column headings I choose. How can I create a single loop and achieve this requirement? My relevant loop is as follows:

```
   foreach (Control item in Controls)
   {
       checkBox = item as CheckBox;

       for (int l = 0; l < listSecili.Count; l++)
       {
           if (item.Text == listSecili[l])
           {
               for (int s = 0; s < bolunmusDeger.Count; s++)
               {
                   xlWorkSheet2.Cells[s + 2, l].Value = bolunmusDeger[s].SiparisSaati;
                   xlWorkSheet2.Cells[s + 2, l].Value = bolunmusDeger[s].MusteriAdi;
                   xlWorkSheet2.Cells[s + 2, l].Value = bolunmusDeger[s].MusteriSoyadi;
                   xlWorkSheet2.Cells[s + 2, l].Value = bolunmusDeger[s].Telefon;
                   xlWorkSheet2.Cells[s + 2, l].Value = bolunmusDeger[s].Urunler;
                   xlWorkSheet2.Cells[s + 2, l].Value = bolunmusDeger[s].Tutar;
                   xlWorkSheet2.Cells[s + 2, l].Value = bolunmusDeger[s].Kanal;
                   xlWorkSheet2.Cells[s + 2, l].Value = bolunmusDeger[s].Kurye;
                   xlWorkSheet2.Cells[s + 2, l].Value = bolunmusDeger[s].Odeme;
                   xlWorkSheet2.Cells[s + 2, l].Value = bolunmusDeger[s].Durum;
                   xlWorkSheet2.Cells[s + 2, l].Value = bolunmusDeger[s].Notlar;
               }
           }
       }
   }
```

I tried a lot of thing but cannot solve it.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the question like this way. Maybe some of friends take forward the solution.

```
      int a=0;

       foreach (Control item in this.Controls)
   {
       if (item.GetType() == typeof(System.Windows.Forms.CheckBox))
       {
           if ((item as System.Windows.Forms.CheckBox).Name == "chck_Sipariş Saati" && (item as System.Windows.Forms.CheckBox).Checked == true)
           {
               a++;
               for (int i = 0; i < bolunmusDeger.Count; i++)
               {
                   xlWorkSheet2.Cells[i + 2, a].Value2 = bolunmusDeger[i].SiparisSaati;
                   xlWorkSheet2.Columns.AutoFit();

                   Excell.Borders border = xlWorkSheet2.Cells[i + 2, a].Borders;
                   BordersForArea(border);

                   tsPB.Increment(i);
               }
           }


           if ((item as System.Windows.Forms.CheckBox).Name == "chck_Müşteri Adı" && (item as System.Windows.Forms.CheckBox).Checked == true)
           {
               a++;
               for (int i = 0; i < bolunmusDeger.Count; i++)
               {
                   xlWorkSheet2.Cells[i + 2, a].Value2 = bolunmusDeger[i].MusteriAdi;
                   xlWorkSheet2.Columns.AutoFit();

                   Excell.Borders border = xlWorkSheet2.Cells[i + 2, a].Borders;
                   BordersForArea(border);

                   tsPB.Increment(i);
               }
           }


           if ((item as System.Windows.Forms.CheckBox).Name == "chck_Müşteri Soyadı" && (item as System.Windows.Forms.CheckBox).Checked == true)
           {
               a++;
               for (int i = 0; i < bolunmusDeger.Count; i++)
               {
                   xlWorkSheet2.Cells[i + 2, a].Value2 = bolunmusDeger[i].MusteriSoyadi;
                   xlWorkSheet2.Columns.AutoFit();

                   Excell.Borders border = xlWorkSheet2.Cells[i + 2, a].Borders;
                   BordersForArea(border);

                   tsPB.Increment(i);
               }
           }


           if ((item as System.Windows.Forms.CheckBox).Name == "chck_Telefon" && (item as System.Windows.Forms.CheckBox).Checked == true)
           {
               a++;
               for (int i = 0; i < bolunmusDeger.Count; i++)
               {
                   xlWorkSheet2.Cells[i + 2, a].Value2 = bolunmusDeger[i].Telefon;
                   xlWorkSheet2.Columns.AutoFit();

                   Excell.Borders border = xlWorkSheet2.Cells[i + 2, a].Borders;
                   BordersForArea(border);

                   tsPB.Increment(i);
               }
           }


           if ((item as System.Windows.Forms.CheckBox).Name == "chck_Ürünler" && (item as System.Windows.Forms.CheckBox).Checked == true)
           {
               a++;
               for (int i = 0; i < bolunmusDeger.Count; i++)
               {
                   xlWorkSheet2.Cells[i + 2, a].Value2 = bolunmusDeger[i].Urunler;
                   xlWorkSheet2.Columns.AutoFit();

                   Excell.Borders border = xlWorkSheet2.Cells[i + 2, a].Borders;
                   BordersForArea(border);

                   tsPB.Increment(i);
               }
           }


           if ((item as System.Windows.Forms.CheckBox).Name == "chck_Tutar" && (item as System.Windows.Forms.CheckBox).Checked == true)
           {
               a++;
               for (int i = 0; i < bolunmusDeger.Count; i++)
               {
                   xlWorkSheet2.Cells[i + 2, a].Value2 = bolunmusDeger[i].Tutar;
                   xlWorkSheet2.Columns.AutoFit();

                   Excell.Borders border = xlWorkSheet2.Cells[i + 2, a].Borders;
                   BordersForArea(border);

                   tsPB.Increment(i);
               }
           }


           if ((item as System.Windows.Forms.CheckBox).Name == "chck_Kanal" && (item as System.Windows.Forms.CheckBox).Checked == true)
           {
               a++;
               for (int i = 0; i < bolunmusDeger.Count; i++)
               {
                   xlWorkSheet2.Cells[i + 2, a].Value2 = bolunmusDeger[i].Kanal;
                   xlWorkSheet2.Columns.AutoFit();

                   Excell.Borders border = xlWorkSheet2.Cells[i + 2, a].Borders;
                   BordersForArea(border);

                   tsPB.Increment(i);
               }
           }


           if ((item as System.Windows.Forms.CheckBox).Name == "chck_Kurye" && (item as System.Windows.Forms.CheckBox).Checked == true)
           {
               a++;
               for (int i = 0; i < bolunmusDeger.Count; i++)
               {
                   xlWorkSheet2.Cells[i + 2, a].Value2 = bolunmusDeger[i].Kurye;
                   xlWorkSheet2.Columns.AutoFit();

                   Excell.Borders border = xlWorkSheet2.Cells[i + 2, a].Borders;
                   BordersForArea(border);

                   tsPB.Increment(i);
               }
           }


           if ((item as System.Windows.Forms.CheckBox).Name == "chck_Ödeme" && (item as System.Windows.Forms.CheckBox).Checked == true)
           {
               a++;
               for (int i = 0; i < bolunmusDeger.Count; i++)
               {
                   xlWorkSheet2.Cells[i + 2, a].Value2 = bolunmusDeger[i].Odeme;
                   xlWorkSheet2.Columns.AutoFit();

                   Excell.Borders border = xlWorkSheet2.Cells[i + 2, a].Borders;
                   BordersForArea(border);

                   tsPB.Increment(i);
               }
           }


           if ((item as System.Windows.Forms.CheckBox).Name == "chck_Durum" && (item as System.Windows.Forms.CheckBox).Checked == true)
           {
               a++;
               for (int i = 0; i < bolunmusDeger.Count; i++)
               {
                   xlWorkSheet2.Cells[i + 2, a].Value2 = bolunmusDeger[i].Durum;
                   xlWorkSheet2.Columns.AutoFit();

                   Excell.Borders border = xlWorkSheet2.Cells[i + 2, a].Borders;
                   BordersForArea(border);

                   tsPB.Increment(i);
               }
           }


           if ((item as System.Windows.Forms.CheckBox).Name == "chck_Not" && (item as System.Windows.Forms.CheckBox).Checked == true)
           {
               a++;
               for (int i = 0; i < bolunmusDeger.Count; i++)
               {
                   xlWorkSheet2.Cells[i + 2, a].Value2 = bolunmusDeger[i].Notlar;
                   xlWorkSheet2.Columns.AutoFit();

                   Excell.Borders border = xlWorkSheet2.Cells[i + 2, a].Borders;
                   BordersForArea(border);

                   tsPB.Increment(i);
               }
           }
       }
   }
```